# Extent report test status recording for failure

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

I am trying to execute tests and using Extent report to integrate my tests for reporting purpose. I wrote test.log pass status only. Not getting how to log failure too keeping in mind I am using assert to validate.

```
public class Logintest extends Basetest {

    Loginpage ls;
    Homepage hpg;
    

    

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        initialization();
        ls = new Loginpage();
        hpg = new Homepage();
        
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] validcredentialsdataprovider() throws Exception {
        Test_Util ts = new Test_Util();
        return ts.excelutil(0);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] invalidcredentialsdataprovider() throws Exception {
        Test_Util ts = new Test_Util();
        return ts.excelutil(1);
    }

    

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifysuccessfullogin() throws Exception {
        hpg = ls.clickonloginbtn();

        String actualtitle = hpg.gettitle();
        String expectedtitle = "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle, expectedtitle)
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test passed");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, dataProvider = "validcredentialsdataprovider")
    public void verifyloginwithvaliddata(String un, String pword) throws Exception {
        ls.verifyloginthroughdatadrivenapproach(un, pword);
        Assert.assertEquals(hpg.gettitle(), "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage");
        
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test passed");
        
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, dataProvider = "invalidcredentialsdataprovider")
    public void verifyloginwithinvaliddata(String un, String pword) throws Exception {
        ls.verifyloginthroughdatadrivenapproach(un, pword);
        Test_Util.forcedwait(5);
        String s = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(s, "User or Password is not valid");
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        Test_Util.forcedwait(2);
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test passed");

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }


    
}
```

Please help.I tried various things like using ITestResult listener but it is failing and returning null every time I try to execute. I tried testResult.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS, testResult.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE in if else condition but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you assert something - you need to "write" it into the report object.

Comment: Tried test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test passed"); but what to do in case test fails? I need to log failure too.